# Looking for a connector with only images to go on

Tags: connector, automotive, adapter

[image: Connector to car's accelerator pedal]

I'm trying to find the connector used for my vehicle's accelerator pedal.

Are there any strategies for finding connectors like this?

Comment: Do a parametric search on one of the distributor websites. If you narrow it down by pin count, pitch, features (locking, shrouded, sealed etc.) you may only have a couple of hundred pics to look through.

Comment: Also, you may be able to look it up based on the model of the vehicle in question.

Comment: That was a great suggestion, this looks like it might be similar, the holes look a little big based on the diagram though, I haven't pulled out my own connector to see what the exact measurements yet: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Aptiv-formerly-Delphi/15326830?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs7eK6h2EBtKhwe%252BwsTRcyjBxpFFghONg4%3D

Comment: Looks automotive to me...

Comment: I found it by focusing on the application instead of the actual connector, just searched "mazda accelerator connector"
 and found this https://www.aliexpress.com/item/6-way-female-male-sumitomo-accelerator-pedal-auto-connector-For-Toyota-LEXUS-SUBARU-DAIHATSU-MAZDA-SUZUKI/32948484402.html

Comment: Could you not cut one out of a junkyard car?

Answer (score 0):

This is a proprietary automotive connector. It might be possible that the same connector is shared among different vehicles within the same automotive group, or regional group. The best strategy is to look in service manuals and identify manufacturer's spare part number. Next best strategy is junk yard.